# how can add class to next two element and remove from current two?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add active class to next two li and remove from current these two active classes.

```
<ul class="bottomNavi_ul clearfix">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">BUSINESS</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">DESIGN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">INTERIOR</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TECHNOLOGY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SAFETY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">INFORMATION</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried with different ways but I couldn't find any solution

```
$('.bottomNavi_ul li:nth-child(1), .bottomNavi_ul li:nth-child(2)').addClass('activeNavLi');
$("#nextLi").click(function() {
  var nextEle = $(".bottomNavi_ul li").nextAll('.activeNavLi').length;
  if (nextEle == 4) {
    $('.bottomNavi_ul li:nth-child(1), .bottomNavi_ul li:nth-child(2)').removeClass('activeNavLi');
    $('.bottomNavi_ul li:nth-child(3), .bottomNavi_ul li:nth-child(4)').addClass('activeNavLi');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `nextAll()` and `:lt()`

```js
$('ul .active')
  .removeClass('active')
  .last()
  .nextAll(':lt(2)')
  .addClass('active')
```

```css
.active a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="bottomNavi_ul clearfix">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">BUSINESS</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">DESIGN</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">INTERIOR</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">TECHNOLOGY</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">SAFETY</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">INFORMATION</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like this answer more than mine.  It's shorter and more intuitive.

Comment: sorry i couldn't mention it when i click on next then it should be active class to next two li

Comment: @saira just place this code inside `$("#nextLi").click( ... )`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using `.nextAll()` and a `.filter()`. I would just filter based on index and grab the first two.

```js
$('.active')
  .removeClass('active')          // remove the inital classes
  .last()                         // target the last of your selection
  .nextAll()                      // grab all the following siblings
  .filter(i => i < 2)             // filter down to only the following two based on index
  .addClass('active')             // add the active class
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bottomNavi_ul clearfix">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">BUSINESS</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">DESIGN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">INTERIOR</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TECHNOLOGY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SAFETY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">INFORMATION</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you can't use ES6 syntax, just use `.filter(function(i){ return i < 2 })`

Answer (score 0):

Try this! It works well using Vanilla JS only and The modulus operator (%) which returns the division remainder in order to stay inside the 'li' elements without getting out of the array. (P.S: I added one 'li' tag in order to test it in an odd number of 'li' tags)

```
<style>
    .active{background-color: red;}
</style>

<ul class="bottomNavi_ul clearfix">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">BUSINESS</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">DESIGN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">INTERIOR</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TECHNOLOGY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SAFETY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">INFORMATION</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">INFORMATION</a></li>
</ul>

<button id="button1">Click Me!</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", moveClasses);

function moveClasses(){
    let listChildren = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");

    for(let i=0; i<listChildren.length; i++){
        if(listChildren[i].className == "active")
        {
            listChildren[i].className ="";
            //lets first handle a special case: first and last elements have class 'active'
            if(i == 0 && listChildren[listChildren.length-1].className == "active"){
                //so we have to elements have 'active' class but they are not one after another,
                //the first one is the first child, and the second one is the last child                            
                listChildren[(i+1)%listChildren.length].className ="active";
                listChildren[(i+2)%listChildren.length].className ="active";
                listChildren[listChildren.length-1].className = "";
                return;
            }                       
            listChildren[(i+1)%listChildren.length].className ="";
            listChildren[(i+2)%listChildren.length].className ="active";
            listChildren[(i+3)%listChildren.length].className ="active";
            break;
        }        
    }                
}
</script>
```